# How to merge multiple hashes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash

```
h  = { a: 1 }
h2 = { b: 2 }
h3 = { c: 3 }
```

Hash#merge works for 2 hashes: `h.merge(h2)`

How to merge 3 hashes?

`h.merge(h2).merge(h3)` works but is there a better way?

Comment: As of Ruby 2.6, `merge` can take multiple hashes as arguments. [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548496/how-to-merge-multiple-hashes-in-ruby/53342567#answer-53342567).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
h, h2, h3  = { a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }
a  = [h, h2, h3]

p Hash[*a.map(&:to_a).flatten] #= > {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

Edit: This is probably the correct way to do it if you have many hashes:

```
a.inject{|tot, new| tot.merge(new)}
# or just
a.inject(&:merge)
```

Comment: That works for me 'as is', but not so much when it's more like h1, h2, h3 = { a: 1, b: 4}, { b: 2, c: 5}, {c: 3, a: 6}

Comment: Sorry, I was to quick to answer, see my update. In you example you have the key :a two times, one will be overwritten as a hash only can have distinct keys.

Comment: Note that `array.reduce(&:merge)` is going to give you the same result as `inject` (`inject` is just an alias of `reduce`)

Comment: Can someone elaborate the first solution. I didn't understand what p "Hash[*a.map(&:to_a).flatten]" does

Comment: @ZealousCoder I'm late, but figured I'd drop an answer. `Hash[]` will accept a series of arguments and build a hash by pairing them up. As such, if you generate an ordered array from the hashes (via `a.map(&:to_a).flatten`) and use the splat operator to pass them as args, it will work nicely. However, `Hash[]` also accepts an array of 2-ary arrays representing k-v pairs and I would have written it as `Hash[*a.flat_map(&:to_a)]`

Answer (score 23):

Since **Ruby 2.0** on that can be accomplished more graciously:

```
h.merge **h1, **h2
```

And in case of overlapping keys - the latter ones, of course, take precedence:

```
h  = {}
h1 = { a: 1, b: 2 }
h2 = { a: 0, c: 3 }

h.merge **h1, **h2
# => {:a=>0, :b=>2, :c=>3}

h.merge **h2, **h1
# => {:a=>1, :c=>3, :b=>2}
```

Comment: What `**` does?

Comment: @ArnoldRoa - it unpackages the hash, analogous to the single splat operator ('*') for arrays.

Comment: Thanks @jayqui, that's a very important "gotcha".

Comment: Also note if for any reason `h1` and `h2` are `{}`. It'll raise and error. `h.merge(**{}, **{})`

Answer (score 20):

You can just do

```
[*h,*h2,*h3].to_h
# => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

This works whether or not the keys are `Symbol`s.

Answer (score 19):

Ruby 2.6 allows `merge` to take multiple arguments:

```
h  = { a: 1 }
h2 = { b: 2 }
h3 = { c: 3 }
h4 = { 'c' => 4 }
h5 = {}

h.merge(h2, h3, h4, h5) # => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, "c"=>4}
```

This works with `Hash.merge!` and `Hash.update` too. Docs for this [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Hash.html#method-i-merge).

Also takes empty hashes and keys as symbols *or* strings.

Much simpler :)

Comment: Giving `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)`

Comment: Are you using Ruby 2.6 @RajanVerma? This is introduced there; with prior versions you'll get the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 8):

#### Answer using `reduce` (same as `inject`)

```
hash_arr = [{foo: "bar"}, {foo2: "bar2"}, {foo2: "bar2b", foo3: "bar3"}]

hash_arr.reduce { |acc, h| (acc || {}).merge h }
# => {:foo2=>"bar2", :foo3=>"bar3", :foo=>"bar"}
```

#### Explanation

For those beginning with Ruby or functional programming, I hope this brief explanation might help understand what's happening here.

The `reduce` method when called on an Array object (`hash_arr`) will iterate through each element of the array with the returned value of the block being stored in an accumulator (`acc`). Effectively, the `h` parameter of my block will take on the value of each hash in the array, and the `acc` parameter will take on the value that is returned by the block through each iteration.

We use `(acc || {})` to handle the initial condition where `acc` is nil. Note that the `merge` method gives priority to keys/values in the original hash. This is why the value of `"bar2b"` doesn't appear in my final hash.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Just because I happened to come across this. In `reduce` and `inject` the accumulator (or memo) is passed as the initial argument to the block rather than the final argument as this suggests (unlike `each_with_object`)

Comment: Ah! Thank you @engineersmnky for noticing this. I've updated my answer! Great catch!

Comment: This helped me immensely. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

To build upon @Oleg Afanasyev's answer, you can also do this neat trick:

```
h  = { a: 1 }
h2 = { b: 2 }
h3 = { c: 3 }

z = { **h, **h2, **h3 }  # => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

Cheers!

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris Yes, that is a downside of this approach.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Hash  
  def multi_merge(*args)
    args.unshift(self)
    args.inject { |accum, ele| accum.merge(ele) }
  end
end
```

That should do it. You could easily monkeypatch that into Hash as I have shown.

Answer (score 3):

```
newHash = [h, h2, h3].each_with_object({}) { |oh, nh| nh.merge!(oh)}
# => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

Comment: The one thing @AGS is doing right here is using `#merge!` instead of `#merge`. `#merge`, alias `#update`, is significantly faster in this case.

Comment: Worked well for me since I believe most of the other methods described here don't work for Ruby v1.9

Answer (score 3):

Here are the 2 monkeypatched ::Hash instance methods we use in our app. Backed by Minitest specs. They use `merge!` instead of `merge` internally, for performance reasons.

```
class ::Hash

  # Merges multiple Hashes together. Similar to JS Object.assign.
  #   Returns merged hash without modifying the receiver.
  #
  # @param *other_hashes [Hash]
  #
  # @return [Hash]
  def merge_multiple(*other_hashes)
    other_hashes.each_with_object(self.dup) do |other_hash, new_hash|
      new_hash.merge!(other_hash)
    end
  end

  # Merges multiple Hashes together. Similar to JS Object.assign.
  #   Modifies the receiving hash.
  #   Returns self.
  #
  # @param *other_hashes [Hash]
  #
  # @return [Hash]
  def merge_multiple!(*other_hashes)
    other_hashes.each(&method(:merge!))

    self
  end

end
```

Tests:

```
describe "#merge_multiple and #merge_multiple!" do
  let(:hash1) {{
    :a => "a",
    :b => "b"
  }}
  let(:hash2) {{
    :b => "y",
    :c => "c"
  }}
  let(:hash3) {{
    :d => "d"
  }}
  let(:merged) {{
    :a => "a",
    :b => "y",
    :c => "c",
    :d => "d"
  }}

  describe "#merge_multiple" do
    subject { hash1.merge_multiple(hash2, hash3) }

    it "should merge three hashes properly" do
      assert_equal(merged, subject)
    end

    it "shouldn't modify the receiver" do
      refute_changes(->{ hash1 }) do
        subject
      end
    end
  end

  describe "#merge_multiple!" do
    subject { hash1.merge_multiple!(hash2, hash3) }

    it "should merge three hashes properly" do
      assert_equal(merged, subject)
    end

    it "shouldn't modify the receiver" do
      assert_changes(->{ hash1 }, :to => merged) do
        subject
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, you can do it also this way:

```
a = { a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }
{}.tap { |h| a.each &h.method( :update ) }
#=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

Answer (score 1):

With modern Ruby, you wont even have to use `merge` unless you need to change the variable in place using the `!` variant, you can just double splat (**) your way through.

```
h  = { a: 1 }
h2 = { b: 2 }
h3 = { c: 3 }
merged_hash = { **h, **h2, **h3 }
=> { a: 1, b: 2, c:3 }
```